Redundant XMLNS attributes when creating XML using multiple namespaces
The code I have:
$xmlns = [
    'xmlns' => 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/',
    'rsm' => 'urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CrossIndustryInvoice:100',
    'ram' => 'urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100',
    'qdt' => 'urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:Standard:QualifiedDataType:100',
    'udt' => 'urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100',
    'xsi' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
];

$document = new DOMDocument();
$root = $document->createElementNS($xmlns['rsm'], 'rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice');
$root->setAttributeNS($xmlns['xmlns'], 'xmlns:ram', $xmlns['ram']);
$root->setAttributeNS($xmlns['xmlns'], 'xmlns:qdt', $xmlns['qdt']);
$root->setAttributeNS($xmlns['xmlns'], 'xmlns:udt', $xmlns['udt']);
$root->setAttributeNS($xmlns['xmlns'], 'xmlns:xsi', $xmlns['xsi']);
$document->appendChild($root);

$parent = $document->createElementNS($xmlns['rsm'], 'ExchangedDocumentContext');
$sub = $document->createElementNS($xmlns['ram'], 'GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter');
$child = $document->createElementNS($xmlns['ram'], 'ID', 'urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017');
$sub->appendChild($child);
$parent->appendChild($sub);
$root->appendChild($parent);

$parent = $document->createElementNS($xmlns['rsm'], 'ExchangedDocument');
$child = $document->createElementNS($xmlns['ram'], 'ID', 'LoremIpsum');
$parent->appendChild($child);
$root->appendChild($parent);

return $document->saveXML();

The result I get:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice xmlns:rsm="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CrossIndustryInvoice:100" xmlns:ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100" xmlns:qdt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:Standard:QualifiedDataType:100" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <rsm:ExchangedDocumentContext>
    <ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter xmlns="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100">
      <ram:ID>urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017</ram:ID>
    </ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
  </rsm:ExchangedDocumentContext>
  <rsm:ExchangedDocument>
    <ram:ID xmlns="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100">LoremIpsum</ram:ID>
  </rsm:ExchangedDocument>
</rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice>

The result I expect:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice xmlns:rsm="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CrossIndustryInvoice:100" xmlns:ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100" xmlns:qdt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:Standard:QualifiedDataType:100" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <rsm:ExchangedDocumentContext>
    <ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
      <ram:ID>urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017</ram:ID>
    </ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
  </rsm:ExchangedDocumentContext>
  <rsm:ExchangedDocument>
    <ram:ID>LoremIpsum</ram:ID>
  </rsm:ExchangedDocument>
</rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice>

Why are there these additional definition of XML namespaces in the child elements? I know, that I can use createElement('ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter'); instead of createElementNS($xmlns['ram'], 'GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter');, but that doesn't feel good or right.
How to do this correctly but still get rid of these namespace re-declarations?

Good job describing the difference between what you got and what you wanted. I would ask the further question, why does getting rid of the redundant declarations matter to you? AFAICT, they're not wrong; no element or attribute is in the incorrect namespace because of them. The XML result that you're getting is technically indistinguishable from the XML you would prefer, to any downstream XML tools that will receive it. I agree it's ugly, but if it's not for human consumption, does it matter?

Thank you for the praise. I think I had already read that it is not technically wrong if the attributes are also output. However, the final XML will contain several hundred elements of this type and I will also be processing very large quantities of XML. I therefore think that there is a certain potential for saving memory. It can be sustainable ;-)

When I ran into this issue at the time I ended up basically writing an XML writing library that handles this better. Not sure how well it holds up but it's still maintained: https://packagist.org/packages/sabre/xml

My mistake. The cause lies in the order in which the elements are inserted into the XML. When changing the existing code:
$parent = $document->createElementNS($xmlns['rsm'], 'ExchangedDocumentContext');
$sub = $document->createElementNS($xmlns['ram'], 'GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter');
$child = $document->createElementNS($xmlns['ram'], 'ID', 'urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017');
$sub->appendChild($child);
$parent->appendChild($sub);
$root->appendChild($parent);

to:
$parent = $document->createElementNS($xmlns['rsm'], 'ExchangedDocumentContext');
$root->appendChild($parent);
$sub = $document->createElementNS($xmlns['ram'], 'GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter');
$parent->appendChild($sub);
$child = $document->createElementNS($xmlns['ram'], 'ID', 'urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017');
$sub->appendChild($child);

I get exactly what I want. Notice the change: Instead of preparing whole node tree and appending it to root at least, I append newly created elements immediately to DOM tree.

At the append call it looks up the namespace in the ancestor nodes. If it is not available it will add a local definition. Optimising the namespace definitions would have a major performance impact for the DOM operations so it is very limited.
